# table data reloading issue

Tags: iphone, tableview, reload

see below code, it removes object from array but it not reloading table

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSLog(@" commitEditingStyle");
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        NSLog(@" commitEditingStyle Delete ");
        [self.arry removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadData];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {
        NSLog(@" commitEditingStyle Insert ");
        [self.arry insertObject:@"New Row" atIndex:[arry count]];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

also i have `[tableView reloadData]` written in `ViewWillAppear` & `ViewDidLoad` but it not reloading.

`TableView` is added tothe ViewController through the storyboard & IBoutlet is added to `.h` file

Comment: From where you are getting the self.arry data ? Where are you adding that data ?

Comment: You must either send your message to your outlet (if you have one i.e.  `self.tableView`) or directly to the tableview that called the delegate method: `[aTableView reloadData];` (notice the `a`)

Comment: you check insert and remove both not work ??? for insert `[self.arry insertObject:@"New Row" atIndex:[arry count]+1];`

Comment: @iPatel:both are not working

Comment: create NSMutableArray in viewWillAppear Method

Comment: @Alladinian:yes ,now it is reloading ,what is that "aTableView"?

Comment: @RavindraBagale That is the name of your tableView instance that is passed to you on your delegate method (take a closer look at the method signature): `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: @RavindraBagale I've also added this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either send your message to your outlet (if you have one i.e. `self.tableView`) or directly to the tableview that called the delegate method: `[aTableView reloadData];` (notice the **a**).

If you take a closer look at the method signature, you'll see that the tableView instance is passed to you as `aTableView` :

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)`**aTableView**...

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
```

forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [arryData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tblSimpleTable reloadData];
} else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    [arryData insertObject:@"Mac Mini" atIndex:[arryData count]];
    [tblSimpleTable reloadData];
}
```

}

use something like that